# java: how to open exist zip file and store bufferedimage into it

Tags: java, zip

I am doing a project dealing with images.
And one function is to zip images. Just as my code shows, it will new a zipOutputStream every time i call compress. As a result, the previous zip file will be overwrite if the path is the same.

```
public void compress() throws IOException {

    String localPath = iProcessor.getPath();

 
    String name = getName(localPath);
    String type = getType(name);

  
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(iProcessor.getImg(), type, os);
    ByteArrayInputStream file = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());

    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));


    out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(name));
    //write into zip
    int len;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 

    while ((len = file.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }

    
    out.closeEntry();
    file.close();
    out.close();
    System.out.println("Create zip file successfully!\n");
}
```

Is there any methods that when I input the same path, it will open the same zipfile and store the image into it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With JDK13 and above, a zip filesystem provides an easy way to modify ZIP files. Once ZIP filesystem is setup you can create directories and copy files using the `Files.createDirectories()` and `Files.copy()`:

```
private static void addToZip(Path zip, Path file, String zipPath) throws IOException {
    try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zip, Map.of("create","true"))) {
        Path root = fs.getRootDirectories().iterator().next();
        Path target = root.resolve(zipPath);
        Files.createDirectories(target.getParent());
        Files.copy(file, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
}
```

For example these calls will update / create ZIP by copying a file to particular path:

```
addToZip(Path.of("/tmp/xyz.zip"), Path.of("/tmp/123.txt"), "some/path/somename.txt");
addToZip(Path.of("/tmp/xyz.zip"), Path.of("/tmp/123.txt"), "anothername.txt");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the whole project is under java jdk 11                      version: openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.12+7 (build 11.0.12+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.12+7 (build 11.0.12+7, mixed mode)